# New ASP.Net JSON files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

What are the responsibilities of the following new files in the ASP.Net 2015 project template:

- global.json
- project.json
- config.json
- package.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global.json` is somewhat an equivalent of the old '.sln' file.  It contains info regarding the solution.

`project.json` is somewhat an equivalent of the old `.csproj` file and also where you'll find your nuget references.

`config.json` is equivalent to the `web.config` / `app.config`, but now it's in JSON format.  It's just one of the many way to hook up configuration.

`package.json` is where you'll find all your `npm` dependencies for usage with client side build process like `grunt` or `gulp`.

and while we're at it... `bower.json` is where you'll find all your client side packages dependencies like `jquery`, `angular`, etc.

Documentation is a bit sketchy right now (as of 2015-05-31), but you should keep an eye on the followings:

- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/global-json.html
- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/project-json.html

Can't find the rest yet, but definitely **docs.asp.net** is where you're going to find the definite answers to these questions.